# Sort vector<int>(n) in O(n) time using O(m) space?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

I have a `vector<unsigned int> vec` of size `n`. Each element in `vec` is in the range `[0, m]`, no duplicates, and I want to sort `vec`. Is it possible to do better than O(n log n) time if you're allowed to use O(m) space? In the average case `m` is much larger than `n`, in the worst case `m == n`.

Ideally I want something O(n).

I get the feeling that there's a bucket sort-ish way to do this:

1. `unsigned int aux[m];`
2. `aux[vec[i]] = i;`
3. Somehow extract the permutation and permute `vec`.

I'm stuck on how to do 3.

In my application `m` is on the order of 16k. However this sort is in the inner loops and accounts for a significant portion of my runtime.

Comment: This question might be better off at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How much larger than n is m?

Comment: How much larger is `m` compared to `n`, larger than `n log n`? Because if that is the case, `O(n log n)` will still be faster than the *linear* `O(m)`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas O(m) space, not time. O(m) time is a simple bucket sort.

Comment: @Adam: If you really mean `O(n)` time, then it cannot be done. To find which of the elements in the `O(m)` space is present you need more than `O(n)`

Comment: @templatetypedef In the very worst case n == m, but in the common case m is O(n^2)-ish.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Why? you have a list of used indices in `aux`. There's got to be a way to use that to avoid a O(m) scan.

Comment: @Adam: How’re you going to traverse that list of used indices in the right order?

Comment: @minitech if I knew I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: @Adam: That’s the thing – it’s the equivalent problem to sorting your list… no advantage in keeping buckets if you have no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for a fact that m = O(n<sup>2</sup>), you can do a base-n radix sort to sort the array. This is like a normal radix sort, but instead of having 2 buckets or 10 buckets, you have n buckets, one for each possible base-n digit of the numbers.

Since the runtime of radix sort in base b is O(n log<sub>b</sub> U), where U is the maximum value, in this case we know that the runtime is O(n log<sub>n</sub> n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n). This is asymptotically faster than O(n log n). It also only requires O(n) memory, which is below the limitation of O(m).

Hope this helps!

Comment: n is variable. It's usually small, but it's variable and can be as high as m in the worst case. In nearly all cases, however, it's 2-3 orders of magnitude smaller. So essentially you're saying have 2-3 iterations of radix sort, on average?

Answer (score 3):

Radix sort, doesn't require the limitation on values being less than m either.

The example implementation below is templated on the int type. If your m is always less than 2^15 you should use a vector of int16_t if possible (or better uint16_t if values are always positive to avoid the offset to handle signed integers). This will require only two sorting passes rather than 4 for 32 bit ints. If you can't change your input type you could special case the code to only do two passes and avoid the signed offset.

This implementation is O(n) and uses O(n) extra space (sort is not in place).

```
template<typename I>
void radix_sort(I first, I last) {
    using namespace std;
    typedef remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)> int_t;
    typedef make_unsigned<int_t>::type uint_t;

    const uint_t signedOffset = is_signed<int_t>::value ? uint_t(numeric_limits<int_t>::max()) + uint_t(1) : 0;
    auto getDigit = [=](uint_t n, int power) -> size_t { return ((n + signedOffset) >> (power * 8)) & 0xff; };

    array<size_t, 256> counts;
    vector<int_t> sorted(distance(first, last));
    for (int power = 0; power < sizeof(int_t); ++power) {
        counts.fill(0);
        for_each(first, last, [&](int_t i) { ++counts[getDigit(i, power)]; });
        partial_sum(begin(counts), end(counts), begin(counts));
        for_each(reverse_iterator<I>(last), reverse_iterator<I>(first), [&](int_t i) {
            sorted[--counts[getDigit(i, power)]] = i;
        });
        copy(begin(sorted), end(sorted), first);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a radix sort in the standard library?

Comment: No, but it's relatively simple to implement and your original requirement is actually a special case where m is the radix.

Comment: The runtime of radix sort with a maximum value of m is O(n log m). If m really is much, much larger than n, this isn't actually any faster than n log n and might be slower.

Comment: For 32 bit integers and radix 256, log m is 4.

Comment: That's true, though it seems strange that this would be the answer given that it doesn't rely on m at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to do:

```
unsigned int aux[m + 1];
bzero(aux, sizeof(aux));

foreach x in (vec) { aux[x]++; }

for(x = 0; x <= m; x++)
  for(qty = 0; qty < x; qty++)
    output(x);
```

Comment: This is O(m) time, though.

Comment: I'd write the first line as `unsigned int aux[m + 1] = {0}` and drop the `bzero` call.